# Python list of dictionaries manipulation

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-manipulation

I have a problem with my current personal script that I made recently which utilizes a series of dictionaries and how to achieve a certain type of structure.

This is the original structure:

```
[
{'airfare': 1000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'yahooEmail@yahoo.com, gmailEmail@gmail.com'},
{'airfare': 2000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'yahooEmail@yahoo.com'},
{'airfare': 3000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'gmailEmail@gmail.com'},
{'airfare': 4000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'liveEmail@live.com'}
]
```

And I wish to achieve something like this, I don't know if this is possible:

```
[{'email_to': 'yahooEmail@yahoo.com',
    'flight_details':[{'airfare': 1000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace' },
                        {'airfare': 2000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace'}]},
{'email_to': 'gmailEmail@gmail.com',
    'flight_details':[{'airfare': 1000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace'},                                                            
                        {'airfare': 3000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace'}]},
{'email_to': 'liveEmail@live.com',
    'flight_details':[{'airfare': 4000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace'}]}]
```

**Edited:**
I'm using python 3.5 and I fetch my data from sqlite database. The data is store in a list of dictionary as per ***original structure*** and I wish to save it on a json file based on the second structure I presented.

Comment: It is possible, but you should clarify more what is it you want - is it a json we are talking about? And have you tried to do it? Which language did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This manipulates the dictionary to the format you require. But exporting as json may be another issue.

```
d = [
{'airfare': 1000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'yahooEmail@yahoo.com, gmailEmail@gmail.com'},
{'airfare': 2000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'yahooEmail@yahoo.com'},
{'airfare': 3000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'gmailEmail@gmail.com'},
{'airfare': 4000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace', 'email_to': 'liveEmail@live.com'}
]

from collections import defaultdict

d_new = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for i in d:
    i['email_to'] = i['email_to'].split(', ')
    for email in i['email_to']:
        d_new[email]['flight_details'].append({'airfare': i['airfare'], 'place': i['place']})

d_new


# defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#             {'gmailEmail@gmail.com': defaultdict(list,
#                          {'flight_details': [{'airfare': 1000,
#                             'place': 'nameOfPlace'},
#                            {'airfare': 3000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace'}]}),
#              'liveEmail@live.com': defaultdict(list,
#                          {'flight_details': [{'airfare': 4000,
#                             'place': 'nameOfPlace'}]}),
#              'yahooEmail@yahoo.com': defaultdict(list,
#                          {'flight_details': [{'airfare': 1000,
#                             'place': 'nameOfPlace'},
#                            {'airfare': 2000, 'place': 'nameOfPlace'}]})})
```

Comment: **jp_data_analysis**, Forget about exporting to JSON, your answer is absolutely what I'm looking for. I've spending almost a week now tweaking list and here you come with only 6 lines of code, amazing. A million thanks to you. Cheers!